# Disable custom Chrome keyword search

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Certain Chrome extensions change my omnibox behavior. For example, if I type "cal", one of my extensions interprets this as a "quick add" for my Google Calendar, rather than a reference to California. The extension has no option to change this. Does anyone know a way to fix this short of disabling the extension altogether?

Answer (score 1):

In case you or anyone else is still looking for an answer to this problem, I will provide my solution.

I'm assuming you meant that the address bar auto-completes the "quick add" when the keyword "cal" is typed.

A quick and easy solution (and the only solution I could find) is to press the F6 button to bring focus to the address bar (if not already focused) and typing a "?" (without quotes) before the word/phrase you want to search for. You can also press Ctrl+e or Ctrl+k to both bring focus to the address bar and auto-insert a "?".

This will also work for search engines you have keywords for.

Example: "?california state parks" (without quotes).